# I can't install solvers in virtual environment

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, cplex, gurobi

I want to work with a package using Jupyter notebook. First, I need to create a virtual environment, which I've done, and then install Gurobi and CPLEX there. Using these commands:

`conda install -n virtualenvname ibmdecisionoptimization cplex` for CPLEX
and these for Gurobi: `conda config --add channels http://conda.anaconda.org/gurobi conda install gurobi`

I get error messages below and because they take so long, I always terminate them before they go further. I don't have this problem without creating virtual environment.

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed
```

Could you please guide me to solve this problem?

Comment: This sounds like your Anaconda environment is broken. Are you able to install any packages at all? I suggest to set up the environment from scratch after updating Anaconda itself.

Comment: Thanks for the input; Yes, I can install other packages.

Comment: Perhaps try: `conda install -n virtualenvname ibmdecisionoptimization::cplex gurobi::gurobi`. However, note that it is generally better practice to specify all required software at the creation of the env rather than doing *ad hoc* installs.

Comment: Can you share the contents of the environment?